# Trying to save to Firebase database but getting undefined error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hoping to get some help saving data to my Firebase database. I'm getting this error in the console "First argument contains undefined in property". Any help or advice solving this would be massively appreciated.

```
//Edit Profile

document.getElementById("profileSubmit").addEventListener('click', function(){

            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            var name, email, photoUrl, uid;

            if (user != null) {
              name = user.displayName;
              email = user.email;
              photoUrl = user.photoURL;
              uid = user.uid;  
            }


            var username= document.getElementById("username");
            var pathway= document.getElementById("pathway");
            var avatar= document.getElementById("avatar");

                if(username !== "" && pathway !== ""){

                // Gets the users input
                var getUsername = username.value;
                var getPathway = pathway.value;
                //var getAvatar =  avatar.value; 

                var editRef= firebase.database().ref("Users/" );

                    editRef.child(uid).set({
                        DisplayName: getUsername,
                        Pathway: getPathway,
                    })

                //Updates Firebase profile
                user.updateProfile({
                    displayName: getUsername
                })

                        $('#successBox').show();
                        $('#successBox').fadeOut(5000); 

                        $('#username').val("");
                        $('#pathway').val("");

                }   //else {

                    //  $('#errorBox').show();
                        //$('#errorBox').fadeOut(5000); 

                    //}
          });
```

Comment: This probably means that getUsername or getPathway are undefined. This error normally occurs when firebase tries to write an object with a property equal to undefined to the database. Check what their values are before you call set(). Another thing that can be causing it is uid being undefined when you try saving your data.

Comment: Thank you, made a silly mistake, renaming the id's have worked!